# Updated object not being returned properly in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

So basically I'm working on a nextjs app which uses authentication. I have a 2 functions which I run on every page load. The first checks if jwt cookies exist and calls another function to validate the tokens if they don't exist. This function is ran from wrapper.getServerSideProps and is passed in the context as ctx. This function works as intended.

```
export const checkServerSideCookie = (ctx) => {
   const access = getCookie("access", ctx.req);
   const refresh = getCookie("refresh", ctx.req);
   if (access && refresh) {
      return checkAuthentication(access, refresh);
   } else return { isAuthenticated: false, token: null };
};
```

The second function is the token validator and this is where the issue arises. I have an object which I intended to update if the validation is successful and leave alone if it isn't. Here is the function

```
export const checkAuthentication = (access, refresh) => {
   const obj = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      token: null,
   };
   const body = JSON.stringify({ token: access });
   axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/jwtoken/verify/", body, {
         headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
      })
      .then((res) => {
         obj.isAuthenticated = true;
         obj.token = access;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         // call new token function using refresh
         console.log("it doesnt work");
      });
   return obj;
};
```

The issue is is that the **.then** does update the object, and when I console.log(obj) in the **.then** it shows the proper obj to return, however when I return the obj it still holds the initial values of false and null. I don't understand what the issue is. I try doing the return in the .then itself but it throughs this error
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAuthenticated' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined`.
What is the issue here? It all seems good but the updated obj isn't returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axios.post` is async, you're returning the `obj` before it gets filled with data from the api response, you can use `async/await` to solve that :

```
export const checkAuthentication = async (access, refresh) => {
  const obj = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    token: null
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ token: access });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/jwtoken/verify/", body, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });

    obj.isAuthenticated = true;
    obj.token = access;
  } catch (e) {
    // do something with the error
    // call new token function using refresh
    console.log("it doesnt work");
  }

  return obj;
};
```

usage (`checkAuthentication` now return a promise ) :

```
checkAuthentication(a, b).then((obj) => {
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: In the usage case, would I do "return checkAuthentication(a, b).then(obj => return obj);" in my first function?

Comment: no, just `return checkAuthentication(a, b)` and whenever you need to access the `obj` do the `then (obj => { ... })` , in your case : `checkServerSideCookie().then(obj => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `checkAuthentication` it immediately returns the `obj` with the default properties. You have an asynchronous operation specified in your function, however you don't wait until it's done. You'd have to rebuild your function the following way:

```
export const checkAuthentication = (access, refresh) => {
   const obj = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      token: null,
   };
   const body = JSON.stringify({ token: access });
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/jwtoken/verify/", body, {
         headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
      })
      .then((res) => {
         resolve({
           isAuthenticated: true,
           token: access
         })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         // call new token function using refresh
         console.log("it doesnt work");
         reject();
      });
    });
};
```

and then call your function the following way:

```
checkAuthentication(access, refresh)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```

You, of course, have multiple options to make your function cleaner, such as by using `async`/`await` etc, but this should give you a quick overview of what is wrong.

Comment: Ok I completely forgot that axios was asynchronous. Thank you for the clarification!